# VBA Error handling and find if I can resume or not

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I've been using VBA for a long time but I can't find what I need on the subject of error handling. Here's my problem:

I want VBA to put data from Excel to Word but sometimes I get error like "Paper format not found" because one of the pc doesn't have legal paper and this stops the program which it shouldn't because it's a silly error.

This is the code that I use to handle error:

```
Public Sub print_data()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo ErrHand 

//code...

ExitHand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Sheets("Login").Select
    Exit Sub

ErrHand:
    MsgBox "Error." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume ExitHand
```

What I'd like to do:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHand 

//code...

ExitHand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Sheets("Login").Select
    Exit Sub

ErrHand:
    'if error is the paper size (err 5889) continue else end sub
    If Err.Number = 5889 then
        'Go back where the error happened then resume next
    Else
        Resume ExitHand
    end if
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resume statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/resume-statement)

Comment: Could you share *//code...*? How will you fix the error for the script to continue printing? Change the paper format? Why is it a *silly error*? If you fix the error in the `If` part, then you can continue with the line that raised the error by using `Resume`. If you don't fix it, `Resume` will lead to an endless loop. If you plan to continue with the next line, you have to use `Resume Next`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 The code is not really the point because it's only the connection to word and copy/paste. I think it's silly because people can change paper format manually after in Microsoft word, the paper size is just a preference. In case the Err.Number = 5889, I would use Err.clear to continue without getting in an endless loop. If I use resume next it will not get back where it was before because it's now in the ErrHand: section...

Comment: @АлексейР I think it's exacly what I needed but it was so obvious that I didn't tought about it...  But could you please explain how resume line number work? VBA doesn't have line number anymore. And if I don't know where it have to resume is there a way to get this number?

Comment: A line number (e.g. `110:`) is like a line label (e.g. `my_label:`), but consists of digits - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#line-number). I think that probably it's beter use `Resume Next` as @VBasic2008 wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the difficulty within the example is that the code mixes ErrorHandling to guarantee reset actions with ErrorHandling to examine specific logic conditions.  If you separate these concerns it leads to simpler logic.  Without knowing the specifics of "//code", consider the following:

```
    Public Sub print_data()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        'SafePrintData does not generate any errors
        SafePrintData
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Sheets("Login").Select
    End Sub

    '//code goes in here...but partitioned to capture specific errors
    Private Sub SafePrintData()

    On Error GoTo ExitOnError
        'Code line(s)
        
    On Error GoTo IgnorableError
        'Code line that can generate 5889

    On Error GoTo ExitOnError
        'Code line(s)
        
    ExitOnError:
        Exit Sub
        
    IgnorableError:
        If Err.Number = 5889 Then
            Resume Next
        Else
            MsgBox "Error." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
            Resume ExitOnError
        End If
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of IgnorableReEntry and just use Resume Next like has been suggested in the comments.

Comment: Modified to use `Resume Next`.